# UNION with cross table where clause

Tags: mysql

```
(SELECT *, 0 AS user FROM table1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE unix >= {$threemonths}) 
ORDER BY unix DESC;
```

I need to add:

`WHERE table2.identifier = table1.identifier` or something

I want to get all from `table1` and only rows from `table2` where `identifier` is found in the results from `table1`'s `identifier` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if this works for you

```
(SELECT *, 0 AS user FROM table1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE unix >= {$threemonths} and exists (select 'Y' from table1 a where a.identifier = table2.identifier)) 
ORDER BY unix DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be

```
  SELECT *, 0 AS user FROM table1
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE unix >= {$threemonths}
  INNER JOIN table1 on  table2.identifier = table1.identifier 
  ORDER BY unix DESC;
```